# How can I add a new QA environment to existing Sitecore Azure Paas setup?

Tags: azure, paas, setup

We have an existing `Sitecore 9` setup in `Azure Paas`. It includes one `CD and one CM server with no xDB`. Now we're looking to add a new QA environment which will effectively be a copy of CM with its own SQL Databases and relevant configurations.

Is there a way to do this apart from using `ARM templates` and the `Sitecore Azure Marketplace module`?

Can I just clone the `CM App Service` and name it as `QA App Service`, then add new databases (core, master, web) while restoring data from `CM databases`?

Comment: I will say yes if are confidant on the CM App service, but just little correction to your thought process rather than creating this in same resource group create/clone everything to new Azure PaaS resource group that will give you ease in working and monitoring. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni - Thanks. I suppose working in a different resource group is just to avoid confusion with existing CM App service & databases.

Comment: Yes it just for to avoid confusion. This will also give separation of concerns and the idea of separate resource group is it will have it's own log system and app insights which won't mix with your existing environment.